# Memory Usage in Linux

Tags: linux, ram, tuning

How to setup limit for process to memory usage?

Similar to open files limit in `/etc/security/limits.conf`:

```
ubuntu           soft    nofile          4096
ubuntu           hard    nofile          8192
```

E.g. while I'm launching python script with raw `eval` of json data from 1.1G file, python takes whole of RAM, while creating objects around each `dict` and `list` in `json.txt`. It hung my machine for 20-30 minutes. Thereafter:

```
# python read_data.py
Killed
```

Ubuntu System is very stable today. Its recovery from hung. Swap going to 8Gb of usage. RAM completely empty, script going off.

I'm trying to find, is this limit, which `killed` my script configurable? Can I tune my system in such way, that every process, which takes more than 70% of current RAM size would be just killed or stopped or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the same file `limits.conf` you can limit:

- `data` - max data size (KB)
- `memlock` - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
- `rss` - max resident set size (KB)
- `as` - address space limit (KB)
- `stack` - max stack size (KB)

So it's pretty much you can do. After setting up limits you can
check this level with `ulimit -a` → you can also use this program 
to set them.
To use `limits.conf` you need `pam_limits.so`.

And last thing is what killed your script. I think it could be OOM killer.
A feature in linux kernel which kills misbehaving processes when they
eat all real memory ;) Use `dmesg` to find out if killer was used. There will be lots of info about candidates to kill and what process precisely was killed.

Cheers,

Comment: Good answer but you might also want to mention the `as` (address space) limitation.

Comment: Thank you, i'm found by myself: `ulimit -v 4000000` protect my system from hunging, while I'm playing with python.

Comment: Note that you cannot limit RSS. http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit - "This limit only has effect in Linux 2.4.x, x < 30".